# Call a method after a certain period of time without blocking

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm making a webserver application, and I have a `Listener` class which waits for connections and spawns an `HTTPConnection`, passing it the new `Socket` created, each time a connect request is made. The `HTTPConnection` class waits for data asynchronously (using `Socket.BeginReceive`).

I need the delayed execution for a timeout. If the client fails to send a full HTTP request after a certain amount of time, I want to close the connection. As soon as the `HTTPConnection` object is constructed, the waiting period should begin, then call a `Timeout` function if the client fails to send the request. Obviously, I can't have the constructor method paused for a few seconds, so the waiting needs to happen async. I also need to be able to cancel the task.

I could do `new Thread(...)` and all, but that's very poor design. Are there any other ways to schedule a method to be called later?

Comment: Sockets already have Timeout properties, why not use them?

Comment: @Henk That wouldn't work. For one, it only works with synchronous `Receive`. For another, that Timeout counts in between bytes being received. Mine needs to wait for a whole HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You could append all postponed events to some ordered data structure and have a background task checking at certain interval if there's a timeout event that have to be executed.

You could save these events in database also (if you have a lot of clients I imagine it could lead to high memory usage).

Also you background task could get all the expired events from the database and handle them at once.

Comment: I thought about that, but I decided not to in case there were a better way, but I guess there isn't so I'll go with that.

Comment: @RogueCSDev Well someone smarter than us might show up and give a better idea, will be good to know. I haven't used my proposition in a server scenario, only in a client mobile application where I've a basic periodic task that all my background services use with different parameters to do all kinds of stuff related to communication. Good luck with your task.